# Hot Swap do Spring apresenta "BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind"

Tags: java, spring-boot, socket

Estou trabalhando com uma thread que fica realizando broadcasts para mapear dispositivos de rede, porem, quando modifico o meu código e o Spring realiza o Hot Swap, recebo a exception "BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind".

Aplicação:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class BroadcastListeningThread {
    public static void startThreadToListenToBroadcasts() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(30333, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"))) {
                    socket.setBroadcast(true);
                    var responseBuffer = new byte[1024];
                    var responsePacket = new DatagramPacket(responseBuffer, responseBuffer.length);
                    String receivedResponse;

                    while (true) {
                        socket.receive(responsePacket);
                        receivedResponse = new String(responsePacket.getData(), 0, responsePacket.getLength());
                        System.out.println(receivedResponse);
                        DiscoveredWEXEquipments.addEquipment(receivedResponse);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Erro:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:394)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:244)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:301)
    at br.com.manager.utils.CommunicationHelper.udpMessage(CommunicationHelper.java:16)
    at br.com.manager.equipmentdiscovery.DiscoverUsingBroadcastStrategy.lambda$0(DiscoverUsingBroadcastStrategy.java:18)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at br.com.manager.equipmentdiscovery.DiscoverUsingBroadcastStrategy.findAll(DiscoverUsingBroadcastStrategy.java:16)
    at br.com.manager.equipmentdiscovery.DiscoverNetworkEquipmentsInNetwork.run(DiscoverAllNetworkEquipmentsInNetwork.java:11)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at br.com.manager.ManagerApplication.main(ManagerApplication.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que tenha identificado o problema. Olhando o codigo, me questionei o que acontecia com a Thread que você criou quando o Spring tentar fazer o reload. Pois ela não foi feita para acabar (`while (true) {`), a menos que se tenha uma exceção ou que a aplicação de fato termine. Então implementei uma solução parecida com a sua e adicionei alguns logs ao código e verifiquei que na primeira interação é criado uma Thread mas ao fazer o reload uma nova é criada usando a mesma porta o que provoca o Erro. Onde a aplicação fica tentando repetidamente iniciar e abrir uma nova Thread que resulta em falha...

A questão agora é como terminar a Thread ao fazer o reload. Pois usar um sistema de portas disponíveis poderia gerar múltiplas Threads fazendo o mesmo processo só que em postas distintas.

**Primeira interacao**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ao fazer o reload**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo para teste**

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Set;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);
    startThreadToListenToWex350Broadcasts();
}

private static void startThreadToListenToWex350Broadcasts() {
    final String threadName = "THREAD_TESTE";
    final Thread thread = new Thread(getRunnable(), threadName);
    thread.start();

    Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().stream()
            .filter(t -> t.getName().equals(threadName))
            .forEach(t -> System.out.println(String.format(" id: %s - name: %s - state: %s", t.getId(), t.getName(), t.getState())));
}

private static Runnable getRunnable() {
    return () -> {
        try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(30333, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"))) {
            socket.setBroadcast(true);
            byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[1024];
            final DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(responseBuffer, responseBuffer.length);
            String receivedResponse;

            while (true) {
                socket.receive(datagramPacket);
                receivedResponse = new String(datagramPacket.getData(), 0, datagramPacket.getLength());
                System.out.println(receivedResponse);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Resolvi o problema criando uma variável para utilizar no while:  `public static boolean exit = false;` e setando como true antes de iniciar as threads:  `BroadcastListeningThread.exit = true;`

Comment: Boa, estava tentando algo na linha de fazer "stop" na Thread ou não recriar caso já existisse.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: Meu supervisor sugeriu criar um metódo dentro da classe `startThreadToListenToWex350Broadcasts()` e usar a annotation _@PreDestroy_, ao invés de setar o valor do `exit` no inicio da aplicação. [_The purpose of this method should be to release resources or perform any other cleanup tasks before the bean gets destroyed, for example closing a database connection._](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy)

Answer (score 0):

Para mim, em uma aplicação SpringBoot já existente usando a IDE IntelliJ v2019.1 a seguinte configuração do projeto e IDE foi o suficiente para o Hot Swap funcionar.

1: Adicionar a dependência abaixo ao pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

2: Abrir o menu de configuração **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler** e marcar a opção **Build project automatically**.

3: Pressionar  **Ctrl + Shift + A** procurar por Registry e dentro deste marcar a opção **compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running**.

4: Fazer um  re-start da IDE.

Conteúdo acima originado do post [Spring Boot Application Live Reload (Hot Swap) with Intellij IDEA](https://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2016/10/spring-boot-apllication-live-reload-hot.html)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O Hot Swap está funcionando normalmente. O meu problema é com a porta do DatagramSocket, que parece que não está sendo liberada durante o Hot Swap, apresentando a exceção acima.

Comment: Entendo, desculpe não ter intendido sua pergunta. Derrubando a aplicação e reiniciando tudo funciona normalmente?

Comment: Correto. Reiniciando manualmente a aplicação funciona sem problemas.